# Can not run PostgreSQL after drop table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've deleted database from PostgreSQL and after this I can do nothing. 
Here what i receive with `createuser`

```
$ createuser -D new_user
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

And this when try to run `psql`

```
$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I've tried above with `root`, `postgres`, `custom` users. Still same output

Also I searched for `pg_hba.conf` like this
 `find / -name 'pg_hba.conf'`
and got this

```
/var/lib/postgres-xc/DN2/pg_hba.conf
/var/lib/postgres-xc/DN1/pg_hba.conf
/var/lib/postgres-xc/CN/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgres-xc/coordinator/CN/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgres-xc/datanode/DN2/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgres-xc/datanode/DN1/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I've changed connection method to `trust`for `localhost` and `IPv4` in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`.

What should I do get rid of this error?

Does connection method in other files above should be edited too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem was that I could not run `psql` command under no user.
Output I received was:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "any role" does not exist
```

`any role` means that I tried to run `psql` under each user on my system(`root`,`postgresql`,`my_user`)

After all I haven't figured out what the problem was, I decided to reinstall PostgreSQL.

And this process turned out rather hard to.

So if you have problems with deleting and reinstalling PostgreSQL, read on.

Here what I had to do.

`echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

`sudo apt-get update`

now we get error about missing `postgresql-common`
to fix it we need to install above package
lets determine its version

```
sudo apt-cache policy postgresql-common
```

and install it

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common=151.pgdg12.4+1
```

we can get error that `postgresql-client-common` not installed
so we need to do the same
determine it version

```
sudo apt-cache policy postgresql-client-common
```

and install

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common=151.pgdg12.4+1
```

after this we can install postgresql like this

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3
```